# python что делает return

Tags: python, return

Подскажите, что конкретно возвращает return и как к нему обратиться?

```
import ctypes

EnumWindows = ctypes.windll.user32.EnumWindows
EnumWindowsProc = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(ctypes.c_bool, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int), ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int))
GetWindowText = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextW
GetWindowTextLength = ctypes.windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW
IsWindowVisible = ctypes.windll.user32.IsWindowVisible

titles = []


def foreach_window(hwnd, lParam):
    if IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        length = GetWindowTextLength(hwnd)
        buff = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
        GetWindowText(hwnd, buff, length + 1)
        titles.append(buff.value)
    return True


EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc(foreach_window), 0)


def main():
    for t in titles:
        if t != '':
            print(t)
    return titles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Я понимаю, что принтит запущенные != пустые окна.
Но, если убираю return в 
def main():
результат не меняется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` возвращает значение из функции.

К примеру, в Вашем варианте в функции

```
def main():
    for t in titles:
        if t != '':
            print(t)
    return titles`
```

Есть указание выводить данные `print(t)`, если они не равны ''.

В данном случае, у Вас уже при выполнении самой функции выводятся данные. А Соответственно `return` не имеет никакой смысловой нагрузки в функции. 
Если же Вы хотите собрать данные в функции, а уже потом их выводить, то Вы можете использовать `return`.
Предположим, что Вы хотите не вывести сразу значения, а собрать их отдельно.

```py
titles = [1, "", 4, 5]
titles1 = []

def main():
    for t in titles:
        if t != '':
            titles1.append(t) ##Если значение не пустое, добавляем в новый массив, вместо вывода на экран
    return titles1

print(main()) ## При вызове функции вернётся значение указанное в return функции
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот пришёл ты в магазин, положил на прилавок деньги (аргументы функции), кассир (функция) их взял, что-то проделал и положил (return) на прилавок товар. Ты можешь его взять или не взять. Если ты товар не берёшь, то естественно нет разницы, положил его кассир или не положил.